# Generating Class VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I was using [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) to generate a Class and I came to a problem. The JSON string I'm using:

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "version": "7.16.1",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "title": "the Dark Child",
      "id": 1,
      "key": "Annie",
      "name": "Annie"
    }
  }
}
```

The Class it generates:

```
Public Class 1
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property 1 As 1
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property data As Data
End Class
```

The thing is that I cannot name a Class 1, I am still trying to find a solution but with no luck yet. Is there a work around this?

Comment: You cannot name an object that starts with a number.

Comment: @Karuntos That was my problem, but it's resolved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be change to `Dictionary`

```
Public Class Example
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property data As Dictionary(Of String, NumberType)
End Class

Public Class NumberType
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

Comment: If I have another block inside `data:` `"1":` and `"2":` how would it work?

Comment: Yes ti will create dictionary with two keys "1" and "2"

Comment: That worked! Not only you gave me a simple answer, you also saved me almost 1k lines of code! (my model had 128 blocks inside data) Thank you! I will remember Dictionary's from now on.